# Search with SQL

Tags: php, sql, select, search

I want to make a good search using PHP and SQL. I'm thinking to use the operator LIKE of SQL (for example: `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country LIKE '%land%`'), but i want that the first elements to be displayed are the ones that begin with "land". How can I do this? I don't want to perform several query to the db because I think it's a bad idea (but I can be wrong).

Comment: `LIKE 'land%'` there you go.

Comment: yes, I know, but i want to display also other solutions, for this reason I'm using LIKE in that way.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean. If you want the ones that start with `land` use as @Fred-ii- suggested. If you want other results explain more.

Comment: ^ my sentiments exactly.

Comment: now wait for "it"... answers comin' right up ;-) edit: ah I'm so clairvoyant.

Comment: I want all the possible results that " %land%'" can find, and I want to show first the ones that start with land, and I think that performs 2 querys is a bad idea.

Comment: you have a variety of answers now, ask them. and you wrote that ^ already.

Comment: Which Dialect of SQL are you using?  MySQL, PostGreSQL, MS SQL Server, Oracle, etc, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could order by whether or not the country begins with `land`. MySQL, which I'm guessing you're using, has a neat feature of translating true/false to 1/0 when referenced in numerical context, so this would be really easy to do:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Customers 
WHERE    Country LIKE '%land%'
ORDER BY Country LIKE 'land%' DESC
```

Other RDBMSs may not have such a treatment of booleans, but you can always implement it yourself with a `case` expression:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     Customers 
WHERE    Country LIKE '%land%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Country LIKE 'land%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Comment: Or, depending on dialect, something like `ORDER BY strpos('land', Country)`?

Comment: @MatBailie yeah, that would work too. For long strings, the `LIKE` approach should perform a tad better, as we don't really care about the result of something like `strpos`, just whether it's 1 or not.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use LIKE to implement search, it has a lot of limitations. But if your use case is simple, here you go:

```
SELECT 1 as orderby, *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE 'land%'
union all
SELECT 2, *
FROM Customers
WHERE Country LIKE '_%land%'
order by orderby
```

this approach allows you to create several levels of sorting

Answer (score 2):

The [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) operator is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE Country LIKE 'land%' 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Customers 
WHERE Country LIKE '%land%';
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return anything beginning with `land` first then everything else.
You will need to specifically list you fields.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM customers
WHERE country LIKE 'land%'
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM customers
WHERE country LIKE '%land%'
AND country NOT LIKE 'land%'
```

Or use sub query in second part of query if you have say a `customerid` field.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM customers
WHERE country LIKE 'land%'
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM customers
WHERE country LIKE '%land%'
AND customerid NOT IN (SELECT customerid
                       FROM customers
                       WHERE country LIKE 'land%')
```